# how to make background video of the website responsive?

Tags: css, html

HTML:

```
<div id="video">
    <video autoplay loop class="video">
        <source src="books.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<section id="meat">
    <P>
        <span class="name">  xxxxxx</span>
        <br/>
        <span class="surname"> xxxxx </span>
    </P>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.video{
    position: fixed; no-repeat;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index:-1000;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

How can I make the video and content responsive? 
CSS, Bootstrap or js any code is helpful. 
Thank you.

Comment: What says Google?

Comment: You might want to inform us how you want the video to be exactly, do you want to have the video playing behind the content above the content? More information is needed!

Comment: Behind the content.

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh I think the `z-index` says it all.

Comment: @NullDev pretty much, but more information would've been appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your question is valid. But your approach is not. I have developed this but loading videos in mobile takes time. So you need to show the video in background for large screens and background image for small screens.
This can be done using Jquery.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
            var width = $("body").width();
            if(width <= 1024){
                $("#media_div").html("<img src='media/images/bg_result.jpg' class='media'/>");                   
            }else{
                $("#media_div").html('<video src="media/video/video.mp4" autoplay="true" mute loop class="media"/>');
                $("#media_div img").css("height","auto");
            }
        });
```

Just make a container and give it an id "media_div". Then write this Jquery code. You also need to do this on document ready event. Because when a page is being loaded for the first time "resize" event is not fired. This will make your code completely responsive even when someone tries to change the browsers width on large screens. Analyse this code. THINK. UNDERSTAND. CODE. ROCK

Comment: Thank you. Finally someone understood what I'm trying to accomplish. 
Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: Hi Monica, I have added a little code. perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the video to be always equal to the screen size, I would solve it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="video">
    <video autoplay loop class="video">
        <source src="books.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
video { object-fit: fill; }

#video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Live Demo:** [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bs4xdnky/) 
(A code snippet here would be kinda useless)
You can check out the demo above and resize the window.

Demo **with content on the video**: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/68qndkjx/)

<s>Also you didn't close your `div`.</s>

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in terms of keeping everything responsive and keep it's aspect ratio:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html{
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
*,::before,::after{box-sizing:inherit}
body{
  color:#fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  position:relative;
  height:100%
}
video{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:50% 50%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:-1;
}
section{
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<!--Video-->
<video autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://files.gamebanana.com/bitpit/rafa_l_de_jongh_-_2d3d_artist_-_80_.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
<!--Content-->
<section id="meat">
  <p><span class="name">xxxxxx</span>
    <br>
    <span class="surname">xxxxxx</span>
  </p>
</section>
```

Can also be viewed on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq8esqna/)

Mainly setting your video to object-fit: cover so your content doesn't get squished and your object-position to the center.
As well as making sure the html, body and section has a height that can be adjusted in percentages and that everything is responsive.

I wouldn't waste an additional div around it though, it wouldn't have any benefits of having it.

Either way I hope it helps!